# /socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, socket.io

I'm struggling with this and I was trying how to figure it out for couple past days. I failed and that's why I'm writing this. I have seen questions from Stack Overflow and other sites but these answers didn't worked out for me.

I have been following this "Get started" from Socket.IO https://socket.io/get-started/chat
Everything worked fine on local servers until I have deployed it on a server.  When I'm trying to enter a site console logs me.

**GET http://8byte.pl/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"**

**Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined at app.js:3**

I know why second one is appearing, but totally have no idea why it can't find socket.io.js file when it was able to find it on local server.

I have tried to create unique GET for this one, and it still wasn't working.

Application is hosted on hitme.pl. They are using CloudLinux and it has option *Setup Node.js App* in Direct Admin. Maybe this information will help.

App address: **8byte.pl/chat**

***server.js***

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http, { cors: { origin: "*" } });
const morgan = require("morgan");

app.use(morgan("tiny"));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/chat", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public", "index.html"));
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("a user connected");

    socket.broadcast.emit("new user connection");
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        socket.broadcast.emit("user disconnection");
    });

    socket.on("chat message", (msg) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit("new message", msg);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, () => "Server started");
```

*bottom of **index.html***

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

*begin of **app.js***

```
const socket = io();
```

Comment: Why does the error message show `http://8byte.pl/socket.io/socket.io.js` (which is port 80), but your server is running on port 3000?

Comment: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

For this line please try to give a full URL of socket.io.

Something like `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>`
or similar CDN url.